# assign 0 when value_count() is not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a column that looks like this:

```
group
A
A
A
B
B
C
```

The value C exists sometimes but not always. This works fine when the C is present. However, if C does not occur in the column, it throws a key error.

```
    value_counts = df.group.value_counts()
    new_df["C"] = value_counts.C
```

I want to check whether C has a count or not. If not, I want to assign `new_df["C"]` a value of 0. I tried this but i still get a keyerror. What else can I try?

```
    value_counts = df.group.value_counts()
    new_df["C"] = value_counts.C
    if (df.group.value_counts()['consents']):
      new_df["C"] = value_counts.consents
    else:
      new_df["C"] = 0
```

Comment: `df['group'].value_counts().reindex(['A','B','C'], fill_value=0)`.

Comment: You'll want to also have `if "C" in new_df and ..."`

Comment: what does the reindex do? @QuangHoang

Comment: this doesn't work @sniperd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is by converting series into dictionary and getting the key, unless not found return the default value (in your case it is 0):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'D']})

new_df = {}

character = "C"
new_df[character] = df.group.value_counts().to_dict().get(character, 0)
```

output of `new_df`

```
{'C': 0}
```

However, I am not sure what `new_df` should be, it seems that it is a dictionary? Or it might be a new dataframe object?

Comment: Great solution +1 . `to_dict` is actually not required here, `Series` itself has a [`get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.get.html) method, so `df['group'].value_counts().get('C', 0)` will work too

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to convert the `group` column to [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) type with specified categories. eg:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']})
print(df)

#   group
# 0     A
# 1     A
# 2     A
# 3     B
# 4     B

categories = ['A', 'B', 'C']

df['group'] = pd.Categorical(df['group'], categories=categories)
df['group'].value_counts()
```

[out]

```
A    3
B    2
C    0
Name: group, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I like this approach if you know all your potentional categories. +1